# Kendo UI for MVC: Export to Pdf not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using **@(Html.Kendo().Grid** in my .cshtml page in mvc application.
I want to export the contents of the grid in the form of a pdf.

I have tried following approaches:

1)

```
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Pdf())
        .Pdf(pdf => pdf
            .AllPages()
            .PaperSize("A4")
            .Margin("2cm", "1cm", "1cm", "1cm")
            .Landscape()
            .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.pdf")
        )
```

2. 

```
 $("#exportToPdf").click(function(e) {
        var grid = $("#CommentsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.saveAsPDF();
    });
```

In both the approaches I am facing the same problem i.e on clicking Export to pdf button I am able to see a stuck progress bar and my screen is freezed.

Please help me to get out of this situation.
Thanking you in advance.
Code sample is appreciated.

Comment: Also facing : https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-searches-dejavu-sans-font-in-missing-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

The DejaVu fonts which are must for default Export To Pdf were missing in my case.
The expected default location of this font is supposed to be: Content/kendo/fonts/DejaVu

I just added DejaVu and the pdf is downloaded.